# Android/ART: What is native thread without managed peer exception?

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I have an Android app with a native lib, there are some callbacks from native to Java. I found the log info from /data/anr/traces.txt when the app is in ANR status, can anyone explain the log to me? What does the "native thread without managed peer" mean? thanks

```
 "<native thread without managed peer>" prio=5 tid=16 Native (still starting up)
      | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x0 self=0xbc430518
      | sysTid=6057 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb7e69b60
      | state=S schedstat=( 6432295108464 1588803713556 7618093 ) utm=483557 stm=159672 core=0 HZ=100
      | stack=0x9c863000-0x9c865000 stackSize=1012KB
      | held mutexes=
      native: #00 pc 00012960  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+28)
      native: #01 pc 000aa063  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ConditionVariable::Wait(art::Thread*)+98)
      native: #02 pc 000b5831  /system/lib/libart.so (???)
      native: #03 pc 000be1ad  /system/lib/libart.so (???)
      native: #04 pc 0023c397  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::CreatePeer(char const*, bool, _jobject*)+90)
      native: #05 pc 0023d177  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::Attach(char const*, bool, _jobject*, bool)+510)
      native: #06 pc 00225f39  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Runtime::AttachCurrentThread(char const*, bool, _jobject*, bool)+16)
      native: #07 pc 001c6aa5  /system/lib/libart.so (???)
      native: #08 pc 000c0f4b  /system/lib/libart.so (???)
native: #09 pc 00f5ce11  /data/app/com.test.testapp-2/lib/arm/test_java.so (???)
```

Comment: Can you provide your configuration files, e.g. build.gradle files and cmake files.

Comment: When you attach a native thread, it will be bound to a corresponding instance of `java.lang.Thread` (i.e. the "managed peer"), and will then be assigned a name. Before these steps have been completed, the native thread will have the generic name `<native thread without managed peer>`.

Comment: it happened in the runtime.  @Michael,  thanks, in what circumstance, this exception could happen?